# react-native video cut in height when fixed to certain height like social media application

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video

I am new to react-native, now use react-native-video and when use resize mode contain and fixed to certain height , video will not show in original size, for showing original size the height makes too long that nearly cover up my screen, what is the way that it will not cut any part when fixed to certain height, Please help...
my code is

```
 <View style={{ width: width,
                            height: height*0.865,
                            position: 'relative',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',}}>
                            <Video source={{ uri: newVideourl }}
                                ref={player}
                                poster={thumbImagee}
                                posterResizeMode='contain'
                                onBuffer={onBuffer}
                                onError={onError}
                                resizeMode="contain"
                                paused={isPlaying}
                                muted={isMuted}
                               
                                style={{width:width,height:'100%',position:'absolute',backgroundColor:'#000'}} />
```